# Redirect inside java interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, interceptor

I would like to create interceptor for error code handling, which will redirect to proper error page in Spring MVC application. The problem is that error code comes from service, which is processed inside the request handler, so I probably need to intercept the service not the request handler.
For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleProducts(ModelAndView mav) {
        //do something
        ...
        //load products
        ResponseMo response = productsService.getProducts();
        //process the response
        mav.addObject("products", response.getData());
        ...
        /do something else
        return mav;
}
```

What I need is to catch the response of getProducts() and if there is error response, I need to redirect... In the project, there are many such handlers and service calls, so I need to solve it on one place. ProductsService is part of the project, same ear.
I was thinking about interceptors, filters, aspects... I can intercept the getProducts() call, but I cannot redirect inside the interceptor, or can I? Or should I use some different approach?

Comment: Should you redirect to the same page for any of the failed service methods?

Comment: Sotirios: Yes, right now according to project specification, there will be only one page, same for all exceptions.. But you know, there is possibility, that there will be new request to redirect to different pages...

Answer (score 1):

see https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Create custom exceptions that will fit into your business cases, then handle the exceptions in the controller. Hope it helps.

Comment: Where should I throw the exception? The problem is that the service does not return an exception but simple error code (String).
So probably I should create interceptor, which will throw exception which will be handled by the @ExceptionHandler. Sounds ok, thanks..

Comment: The purpose of interceptor is totally different. What kind of exceptions you want to catch? if they are unchecked exceptions they can't be declared in the method signature. so you can just handle them in the controller as in the example in the previous link, they handle `@ExceptionHandler({SQLException.class,DataAccessException.class})` which can be raised from their service.

Comment: The problem is that there is no exception raised from the productsService (from example above), error code only. An I cannot change this behaviour. So I cannot use @ExceptionHandler because there are no exceptions... What I was thinking is to create them in some interceptor, which is not good behaviour probably, but I cannot see any other possible solution right now.

Comment: You can always check this error code that is raised from productService and to throw custom exception. Some kind like http error code. 
`if (code >= 500) throw new ServerErrorException();
if (code >= 400) throw new ClientErrorException();` or i didn't get it right.

Comment: Yes, but I have to do it in many request handlers, that is why I need to do it in interceptor - check the code on one place not in every handler.